# WP add_submenu_page with a custom url

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I used `add_submenu_page` to add a new page in wp admin.
The page was created with this url: `domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=mynewpage`.
What I need is to create it with a custom url, like this: `domain.com/mynewpage`.

Is it possible?

If not, how can I change the url to the new one I want?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
If I can't remove the wp-admin so how do I make it `domain.com/wp-admin/mynewpage`?

Comment: you can not remove wp-admin from wordpress admin URL.

Answer (score 0):

the think you want its can not use in wordpress admin panel.
you can build a separate panel for what you want,
you can do this by custom pages [is_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) function.
for security of this page you should give access to administator user..

Comment: with this way you can use domain.com/mynewpage